# Creating a dynamic price on the WooCommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The price of the product depends on the number of products in the store and the number of products sold. That is, the price is dynamically between the primary price and the secondary price, which decreases with the number of product sales. Products at WooCommerce are dynamic.
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

So the price is variable, but not in a set of predefined prices: you could do it with woocommerce variable product.

If the price is related to :

- number of product in the store
- number of product sold

You would need to:

- Hook the a "success order" event, so you can trigger price manipulation depending new product sold total (find the product, update required post_meta to update prices
- Now about the "total number of product in the store", its a bit more complex cause an admin can add some product whenever he wants.

  - A cron, that will run every X hours/days, and update required product prices depending the total number of product in the store
  - Hook on "post created, post updated" backend hook for post_type product, to trigger your new calculation